# Removing SOAP Wrapper From a Message in wso2 ESB

Tags: sequence, wso2, esb, mediator, wso2-esb

I tried to invoke a web service through WSO2esb.My web service is only accepting a soap message like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate/Input" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\Documents and Settings\RoGulk\Desktop\SPM\Envelope.xsd">
    <ns1:Body>
        <ns2:ConversionRate xmlns:ns2="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
         <ns2:FromCurrency>USD</ns2:FromCurrency>
          <ns2:ToCurrency>USD</ns2:ToCurrency>
        </ns2:ConversionRate>
    </ns1:Body>
</ns1:Envelope>
```

But the problem is when I read the input message to the esb, The esb adds a additional wrapper to my meaasage like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns1:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate/Input">
  <ns1:Body>
    <ns2:ConversionRate xmlns:ns2="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
      <ns2:FromCurrency>INR</ns2:FromCurrency>
      <ns2:ToCurrency>NAD</ns2:ToCurrency>
    </ns2:ConversionRate>
  </ns1:Body>
</ns1:Envelope>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I think it can be done by using the 'application/XML' message formatter before I call to my endpoint.But the problem is I don't know how to invoke the 'application/XML' message formatter and where to use it.**
 Guys please help me, Thanks

**EDITED**

I thought that adding my proxy service configuration will be helpful.

In this I am not using default out sequance. Instead of that I am using sequance called "currencyFileWriter" which is responsible for writing a file to a output directory.

This is my proxy service

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CurrencyProxy" transports="https,http,vfs" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="ContentType" value="application/xml" scope="default"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="MessageType" expression="$axis2:ContentType"/>
         </log>
         <log level="full"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="insequance" value="================================Forwerded to out File writer sequance====================="/>
         </log>
         <send receive="currencyFileWriter" buildmessage="true">
            <endpoint key="CurrencyConverter"/>
         </send>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="After" value="============================AFTER SEND================"/>
         </log>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///C:/test/Orginal1/</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///C:/test/Pass1/</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///C:/test/Failures1/</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">currencytest.xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

And tihs is my CurrencyFilewriter sequance

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="currencyFileWriter">
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="sequance" value="=====================RECIVED TO CURRENCYFILEWRITER=========================="/>
   </log>
   <log level="full"/>
   <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" value="result.xml" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <send>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="vfs:file:///C:/test/Out1"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following configuration and I got the following results inside of the VFS folder.

Here's what I've done:

Endpoint Configuration:

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CurrencyConverter">
   <address uri="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"></address>
</endpoint>
```

Sequence Configuration:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="currencyFileWriter">
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="sequance" value="=====================RECIVED TO CURRENCYFILEWRITER=========================="/>
   </log>
   <log level="full"/>
   <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" value="result.xml" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <send>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="vfs:file:///home/ravi/esb/wso2esb-4.5.1/vfs-temp/Out1"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

Proxy Configuration:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CurrencyProxy" transports="https,http,vfs" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="insequance" value="================================Forwerded to out File writer sequance====================="/>
         </log>
         <send>
            <endpoint key="CurrencyConverter"/>
         </send>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="After" value="============================AFTER SEND================"/>
         </log>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <sequence key="currencyFileWriter"/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///home/ravi/esb/wso2esb-4.5.1/vfs-temp/Pass1/</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///home/ravi/esb/wso2esb-4.5.1/vfs-temp/Orginal1/</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///home/ravi/esb/wso2esb-4.5.1/vfs-temp/Failures1/</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">currencytest.xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

This is what is passed from the client (SOAP UI in my case) to the ESB - I've used SOAP 1.2 here by pointing the namespace ns1 to http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns2="http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate/Input">

    <ns1:Body>
        <ns2:ConversionRate xmlns:ns2="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
         <ns2:FromCurrency>USD</ns2:FromCurrency>
          <ns2:ToCurrency>LKR</ns2:ToCurrency>
        </ns2:ConversionRate>
    </ns1:Body>
</ns1:Envelope>
```

This is what the ESB sends to the backend service:

```
POST /CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action="urn:mediate"
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns1:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns2="http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate/Input">
    <ns1:Body>
        <ns2:ConversionRate xmlns:ns2="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
            <ns2:FromCurrency>USD</ns2:FromCurrency>
            <ns2:ToCurrency>LKR</ns2:ToCurrency>
        </ns2:ConversionRate>
    </ns1:Body>
</ns1:Envelope>
```

This is what the web service returns to the ESB and is also saved in the Out1 file:

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 380
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 23 Jan 2013 15:53:53 GMT


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ConversionRateResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">     
            <ConversionRateResult>127.05</ConversionRateResult>
        </ConversionRateResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Hope this helps as with this setup I don't seem to be getting the issue you're having - with the ESB re-wrapping the request. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following property just above the send mediator (before call your endpoint) to remove the additional soap envelope wrapper from the message.

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

I tested it with following sample proxy and it worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="test"
           transports="https,http"
           statistics="disable"
           trace="disable"
           startOnLoad="true">
       <target>
          <inSequence>

             <property name="messageType"
                       value="application/xml"
                       scope="axis2"
                       type="STRING"/>
             <log level="full"/>
             <send>
                <endpoint>
                   <address uri="http://www.google.com"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send>
          </inSequence>
       </target>
       <description/>
    </proxy>
```

Thanks